# web3 contract call does nothing

Tags: web3js, contract-invocation, metamask

I'm trying to call a function contract from web3. The web3 provider is metamask and the metamask popup opens up when it should however when I click confirm I just see a loader and nothing happens. When I click away and open metamask again, it just says that the transaction is approved but not confirmed. The code I'm using is pretty much exactly whats in the docs. Why is this happening?

Comment: You say nothing we can check. What is your code? What is the doc you are following? Did you get a transaction id from metamask? Are you testing agains mainnet or a testnet? Usually transaction not being confirmed quickly might be the gas price is too low, but metamask suggest a fair price.

Comment: @ismael I posted over on SO as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49908044/web3-contract-method-isnt-being-called?noredirect=1#comment86836496_49908044

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be related to metamask history.

Try following this guide: https://metamask.helpscoutdocs.com/article/36-resetting-an-account

If you're using local ganache-cli o similiar things such as testrpc restart those and change network Id.

This bug might lead  to blank metamask too, https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/1999.

Comment: Tried that, not working.